# Do macrophages engulf material in the epidermis?

Tags: human-biology, skin

This question comes from how tattoos work.  From what I understand, the ink particles are something like 100 nanometers in size, which is too big for macrophages to remove them in the dermis.  What I would like to know in that case is are macrophages able to go into the epidermis, or is that too far for them?  In other words, would material in the epidermis just leave the body after that part of the skin grows out?